# How to unhide a hidden letter in sequence using keydown event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to unhide the hidden letter inside the border one by one as user press a matching letter on keyboard. Quite similar to speed typing game. But right now, using "i like learning code" as example, when I press i on keyboard, all the "i" in the sentence shows up, but I want very first letter "i" in the sentence to show up then I press "space" to match the white space that comes after then press "l" and so on. Currently, I'm using window.addEventListener, but I prefer to type inside of a border and I think I need useRef hook for that. But first, how can I change my logic so letter becomes unhided in sequence? I know index has to be involved but not quiet sure how to manipulate it. Here is code in code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sun-3u7b3?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  let sentence = "i like learning code";
 
  const words = sentence.split(" ");
  const [correctLetters, setCorrectLetters] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeydown = (event) => {
      const { key, keyCode } = event;
      console.log(keyCode);
      if (sentence && keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) {
        const letter = key.toLowerCase();

        if (sentence.includes(letter)) {
          if (!correctLetters.includes(letter)) {
            setCorrectLetters((currentLetters) => [...currentLetters, letter]);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);
  }, [correctLetters, sentence]);

  return (
    <div className="pageContainer">
      {words.map((word, i) => (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          {[...word].map((letters) => (
            <p className="letterBorder">
              {correctLetters.includes(letters) ? letters : ""}
            </p>
          ))}
          {i === words.length - 1 ? null : <p className="whiteSpaceBorder"></p>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
.letterBorder {
  border: 25px;
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  min-width: 100%;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.whiteSpaceBorder {
  border: 25px;
  background: orange;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.pageContainer {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightcyan;
  height: 40rem;
  width: 30rem;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's important here is the `index` or location of the character that was pressed. You need to keep track of it. When you use `includes` like:

```
{correctLetters.includes(letters) ? letters : ""}
```

Then there is no difference between first `i` and the second occurrence of the `i`. I tried to recreate what you have my own style:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./style.css";

let sentence = "I like learning to code";

// Update a specific element of an array at the given `index` with `newValue`
function updateAtIndex(arr, index, newValue) {
  return [...arr.slice(0, index), newValue, ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
}

export default function App() {
  // Initially:                  ["i",  " ", "l", "i", "k",  "e", " ", "l", "e", "a", "r", "n", "i", "n", "g", " ", "t", "o", " ", "c", "o", "d", "e"]
  // `k` is pressed:             ["i",  " ", "l", "i", null, "e", " ", "l", "e", "a", "r", "n", "i", "n", "g", " ", "t", "o", " ", "c", "o", "d", "e"]
  // `i` is pressed:             [null, " ", "l", "i", null, "e", " ", "l", "e", "a", "r", "n", "i", "n", "g", " ", "t", "o", " ", "c", "o", "d", "e"]
  // and so on
  let [correctLetters, setCorrectLetters] = useState(
    sentence.toLowerCase().split("")
  );

  let handleKeyDown = useCallback(event => {
    let { key, keyCode } = event;

    // Added `32` keyCode to handle the `space` as well
    if ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || keyCode === 32) {
      let c = key.toLowerCase();

      // Using the callback version of the setState here is important
      setCorrectLetters(current => {
        let firstOccurance = current.indexOf(c);
        if (firstOccurance > -1) {
          return updateAtIndex(current, firstOccurance, null);
        }
        return current;
      });
    }
  }, []);

  // If you use an element that takes the whole screen
  // then you can just assign an `onKeyDown` with a `tabIndex`
  // to avoid using `window.addEventListener`
  return (
    <div className="page" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} tabIndex="0">
      {correctLetters.map((c, index) =>
        c === null ? (
          <span key={index} className="box open">
            {sentence[index]}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <span key={index} className="box lock" />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see the [demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jdstf4)

Comment: What's the purpose of using useCallback hook here? I appreciate you taking your time creating this solution.

Comment: `useCallback` memoizes the function declaration so it doesn't get redeclared on every render. Here an empty array, `[]` says I only want `handleKeyDown` to be declared once on mount. It's just an optimization and it'll work even without it.